# How to cteate a Node inside Main Node of Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how we create node inside a node in firebase android...i need to creat blood_Group node inside kchzdjn...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simples way to achieve this is to use `updateChildren()` method directly on your reference like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference sessionIdRef = rootRef.child("sessions").child(sessionId);
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("blood_Group", "");
sessionIdRef.updateChildren(map);
```

In which `sessionId` is the unique key generated by the `push()` method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanx its helpfull for me

Comment: If you still think my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!